# Customize NSIS uninstaller to delete files with Electron-builder

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I have the following script in my build/installer.nsh file to delete the files on uninstall.

```nsis
!macro customUnInstall
   SetShellVarContext current
   Delete "$LocalAppdata\MyUI\.settings.db"
   Delete "$LocalAppdata\MyUI\.contrib.db"
!macroend
```

However when installing as well the following files are getting deleted. This is how my package.json's nsis section looks like:

```json
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": false,
  "uninstallDisplayName": "Equella Sync Uninstaller",
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
  "runAfterFinish": true,
  "createDesktopShortcut": true,
  "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
  "perMachine": true,
  "license": "license.txt",
  "include": "build/installer.nsh",
  "installerIcon": "build/gadoeicon.ico"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please follow the Microsoft guidelines and use `"createDesktopShortcut": false,`.

Answer (score 0):

If Electron was sneaky and also inserted the macro in your installer, then you could get around that with:

```
!macro customUnInstall
   !ifdef __UNINSTALL__
     SetShellVarContext current
     Delete "$LocalAppdata\MyUI\.settings.db"
     Delete "$LocalAppdata\MyUI\.contrib.db"
     SetShellVarContext lastused
   !endif
!macroend
```

but it is far more likely that it is running the previous uninstaller when you install on top of an existing install. I would assume there is a way to disable this but I don't know anything about Electron builder so I can't tell you which JSON property to set.

A quick look at their source does indicate that you could inspect `$CMDLINE` for `/KEEP_APP_DATA` in `customUnInstall`.

Comment: Yes you are correct it does look like the previous uninstaller is running on top of the new installer even though the flag is set: "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false. Any way prevent this.